# Running multiple EIGRP processes on a router

Tags: eigrp

I am studying about EIGRP at the moment and I came across the option of running multiple EIGRP processes with different autonomous system numbers on a router.

I don't understand in which cases we would actually want to run more than one EIGRP process in our network. Could someone please give me some examples?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running multiple processes is not very common and there are not a lot of examples.

One possible reason for running multiple processes is when there are two separate routing domains (*e.g.* when merging two organizations) and you want to control which routes are redistributed between them for security reasons or overlapping addresses.

Each process joins a separate domain, and you specify specific routes that are redistributed between them.

Comment: I was told before that by using multiple processes, we are breaking up the boundary of EIGRP messages/queries. A message sent in AS1 won’t go all the way to AS2 and that this ensures that we are not flooding the entire routing domain with EIGRP queries and that it's also easier to manage. Is this true?

Comment: In theory, yes.  In practice, summarization and address planning will accomplish the same.